# Error while deploying Flask app on Heroku "Requested runtime not available for this stack"

Tags: python, heroku

I'm trying to deploy an app on Heroku. I have included the `runtime.txt` file and included the latest python version 3.6.3 as suggested, but I'm getting the following error.

```
    -----> Python app detected
 !     The latest version of Python 3 is python-3.6.3 (you are using python 3.6.3, which is unsupported).
 !     We recommend upgrading by specifying the latest version (python-3.6.3).
       Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes


-----> Installing python 3.6.3
 !     Requested runtime (python 3.6.3) is not available for this stack (heroku-16).
 !     Aborting.  More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: Please show the contents of your runtime.txt.

Comment: It might be asking you to use `python-3.6.3` instead of `3.6.3`.

Comment: @Blender Ah that was it. Thank you! I was doing `python 3.6.3` instead of `python-3.6.3`